# Gilbert Strang, Introduction to Linear Algebra (2016 5th Edition), Problem Set 2.4, Problem 28, page 81

Tags: linear-algebra

> 28 Draw the cuts in A (2 by 3) and B (3 by 4) and AB to show how each of
> the four multiplication rules is really a block multiplication.
>
> (1) Matrix A times the columns of B:   **Columns of AB**
> (2) Rows of A times the Matrix B:      **Rows of AB**
> (3) Rows of A times the columns of B:  **Inner products** (numbers in AB)
> (4) Columns of A times rows of B:      **Outer products** (matrices added to AB)

Part of the problem is that I'm not 100% sure what is being asked here. If someone could explain how to solve 1 and 2 below and the differences between them then I think I'd be able to do the rest. I include my attempts at 1 and 2 below:

Q1.) This would be done 4 times: $(2,3) \cdot (3,1) = (2,1) \cdot 4$

$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 & & \\
 & & 
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}
\\
& \\
& 
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& & & \\ 
& & &
\end{array}
\right]
$

Q2.) This would be done 2 times: $(1,3) \cdot (3,4) = (1 \cdot 4) \cdot 2$

$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 & & \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
& & & \\
& & &\\
& & & 
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}
& & & \\ \hline
& & &
\end{array}
\right]
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Strang is just trying to illustrate how to visually perceive, at a glance, the rules of multiplication. I think he just wants you to consider the "blocks" determined by the stated partitioning in each question (i.e. row or columns)

We see that question 1 is simply asking to show $A$ times the "cuts" of $B$, where the blocks defining the cuts are the columns of $B$. So, we have:

$A \bigg[ \quad \bigg| \quad \bigg| \quad \bigg| \quad \bigg]$.

Question 2 just fixes matrix $B$. So:

$\bigg[ \begin{array}
& & & \\ \hline
& & &
\end{array}\bigg]B$